# How to match key value in two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two `arrays`

```
       Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [affiliate_id] => 190
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [affiliate_id] => 946
                )

        )




        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 190
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 246
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [user_id] => 249
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [user_id] => 250
                )

        )
```

Now i want to get an array which has value like this

if `affiliate_id` of first array exists in second array as `user_id`  then i will get its value in third array like

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                    [affiliate_id] => 190
                )
        )
```

i just want `affiliate_id` which is exists in second array as `user_id`

Comment: Dude, write an object and make your life incredibly easier.

Comment: You have to build this function yourself

Comment: @christopher $this->data['users_names'] and $this->data['affiliate_array'] are two array i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = Array(
    Array('id' => 1, 'affiliate_id' => 190),
    Array('id' => 2, 'affiliate_id' => 946)
);

$b = Array(
    Array('id' => 1, 'user_id' => 190),
    Array('id' => 2, 'user_id' => 246),
    Array('id' => 3, 'user_id' => 249),
    Array('id' => 3, 'user_id' => 250)
);

$c = array_map(function ($arr) { return $arr['affiliate_id']; }, $a);
$d = array_map(function ($arr) { return $arr['user_id']; }, $b);

$e = array_intersect($c, $d);

print_r($e);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `in_array()` with loop

```
$a = firstarray;
$b = second array;
$i =0;
foreach($b as $k=>$v) {
 if(!empty($a[$i])) {
      if(in_array($v['user_id'], $a[$i])) {
        $c[]['affiliate_id'] = $v['user_id'];
      }
  }
  $i++;
}
print_r($c);
```

output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [affiliate_id] => 190
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(array('id' => 1, 'affiliate_id' => 190),
              array('id' => 2, 'affiliate_id' => 946));

$arr2 = array(array('id' => 1, 'user_id' => 190),
              array('id' => 2, 'user_id' => 246),
              array('id' => 3, 'user_id' => 249),
              array('id' => 4, 'user_id' => 250));

$count = 0;

foreach ($arr1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    if (in_array($v1['affiliate_id'], $arr2[$count]))
    {
        $arr3[]['affiliate_id'] = $v1['affiliate_id'];
    }
    $count++;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr3);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [affiliate_id] => 190
        )
)
```